# Tag resolution for post previews fails on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, markdown-preview, meta-tags

For example, take the following:

```
[tag:lua] and [meta-tag:bug]
```

It used to appear as following in the preview box in the post editor window:

> [image: previously]

But now, it shows up as:

[image: now]

The resulting post is being parsed correctly so it is just a minor bug. Probably not too many people would notice it either.

---

#### NOTE

The `[tag:lua]` redirects to [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lua) (weird) instead of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) (expected)

Comment: Typed stuff in an answer (without posting) and reproduced both issues. On that note though, `[tag:bug]` gives the desired tag (i.e. it renders as a meta tag).

Comment: Typing `[tag:status-completed]` gives me the red one that we're used to. Makes me wonder if this entire thing was a status-by-design with possibly unintended consequences.

Comment: Yes, it does appear as if these have been flipped. The new header bar was bound to break _something_...

Comment: Meta.TeX.SE has the "old" behaviour; TeX.SE proper has the "new" behaviour. It appears that Meta.SO is now classed as a main site by that bit of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the markdown editor relied on some stuff in the old *top-bar* to find out whether this feature should be enabled or not on a given site. And since the old *top-bar* is no more, it's disabled, always (just on the site(s) / meta.SO where the new [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar) is enabled)

Fix in meta rev `2013.11.15.1646` (proof ^^). Thanks for reporting that.